# Probability Exam Question

Tags: probability

I've had this Maths A'level exam question today and was wondering if my anwers were correct. Here is the question

Anna and Bernard are two of 15 participants taking part in a lottery to win one of the five different cash prizes. Any participant can win at most one prize and prizes are given in decreasing order of value.

A) In how many ways can the prizes be distributed among the participants?

B) What is the probability that:
i) Either Anna or Bernard (or both) win one of the prizes?
ii) Anna wins a larger prize than Bernard (nothing that it is possible that Bernard does not win anything)?

Comment: Would you be willing to share your answers to these questions and perhaps a little explanation as to how you arrived at your answers? Questions without work shown here tend to get looked down on

Comment: My apologies, will fix my post as this is my first time posting on here.

Comment: Please, post only [one question in one post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7132/290189).
Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged
and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) First come up with how many ways there are to select five winners regardless of order. This would be given by:

$$\binom{15}{5}$$

But then we are also given that there are 5 'different' prizes. So if I take my five winners, there are 5 possible ways to give the first prize, 4 possible ways to give the second, etc. So to account for the differing prizes we just need to multiply by the number of ways to order 5 different objects.

$$\binom{15}{5}5! = 15*14*13*12*11$$

This is the total number of ways to distribute 5 different prizes among 15 people.

B) i) First lets use the addition rule of probability, namely for two events $A,B$ the probability of $A$ or $B$ is given by:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

Now let $A$ be the event that Anna is chosen and $B$ be the event that Bernard is chosen. To find $P(A)$ we just need to count how many ways are there for Anna to be selected in the group of 5. And then divide this by the number of ways to choose the 5.

$$P(A) = \frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{14}{4}}{\binom{15}{5}} = \frac{\frac{14*13*12*11}{4!}}{\frac{15*14*13*12*11}{5!}} = 5/15 = 0.3333$$

This is the probability that Anna wins ONE of the prizes, it doesn't take into account which one she wins. Note here that this is also the probability that Bernard wins. In other words, $P(A) = P(B)$. So

$$P(A \cup B) = 2P(A) - P(A \cap B)$$

$$P(A \cap B) = \frac{\binom{2}{2}\binom{13}{3}}{\binom{15}{5}} = \frac{20}{210} = 0.09523$$

$$P(A \cup B) = 2(.3333) - (.09523) = .6666 - .09523 = 0.5713$$

Now it gets trickier, we want to find $P(A > B)$. I'll go about this just by counting all the ways Anna comes before Bernard in the sequence of prizes. The number of ways to distribute the prizes is as in i), $\binom{15}{5}5! = 15*14*13*12*11$

If Anna wins the first prize, then there are 14 people able to win second prize, 13 to win 3rd etc. If Anna wins second prize there are 13 people who can win first, which excludes Bernard, 13 people who can win 3rd prize, now adding Bernard back in. So the final probability looks like this:

$P(A > B) = \frac{1*14*13*12*11 + 13*1*13*12*11 + 13*12*1*12*11 + 13*12*11*1*11 + 13*12*11*10*1}{15*14*13*12*11}$

$$ = \frac{24,024 + 22,308 + 20,592 + 18,876 + 17,160}{360,360} = \frac{102,960}{360,360} = 2/7 = 0.286$$